# Exporting a Unity 3D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was finishing up and exporting on a Unity made game. I was using [this Brackeys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nxKAtxGSn8&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6&index=12) as a guide. In the video after he has done exporting the game out of Unity, at about 8:26 we see that there is only one application that is the game and data folder. Although when I did the same I got something like this. [image: A picture of a computer screen] Where there is the data folder, a mono Bleeding folder, the game and two Unity apps. In the video he exports only the data folder with the game. So should I proceed with his method or export all of these folders and application?

Comment: Maybe, the version of Unity used in the video is different from yours? Did you try what happens if you remove the additional folders?

Comment: yeah the example is for Unity 5.5. .. so from quite a while ago ;) See [Windows standalone Player build binaries](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WindowsStandaloneBinaries.html) to see what else can be created by building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MonoBleedingEdge** where are DLLs that Unity uses to launch your game. Then from that, it uses it to launch other DLLs from `GAMENAME_Data` folder. You can use IL2CPP to pack your game directly into C++ to not use Mono backend and to not have this folder.

[image]

**UnityCrashHandler** is an application that always runs in the background when Unity starts. It looks at the Unity process and will send a report to Unity (and to you if you properly configure Unity) when the application crashes unexpectedly.

**UnityPlayer** is DLL where (part of) Unity Engine native code is contained.

All files and folders are required!

Comment: So if I want to export and share my game I need to export these apps also, right?

Comment: @Is_this_my_username Yes - a whole folder that Unity produces